# Can I use Quarkus Reactive Panache with Oracle R2DBC? Are they compatible?

Tags: oracle, quarkus, reactive, r2dbc, quarkus-panache

The Quarkus Oracle reactive extension is in tech preview for a long time for the RedHat supported build, so I'm looking for alternatives for prod use.

I'm using Mutiny and reactive rest and rest client, but this set up is incomplete without a stable Oracle reactive extension.

Answer (score 1):

Quarkus reactive client for RDBMS is based [vertx sql client](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client/) , which supports the popular databases. But it is not compatible with R2dbc.

You can use the sql client directly, or use Hibernate Reactive(based on vertx-sql-client) API in Quarkus projects.

Check my example project:

- Hibernate Reactive(based PgClient): https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sandbox/tree/master/resteasy-reactive-hibernate
- PgClient:  https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sandbox/tree/master/resteasy-reactive-pgclient
- Hibernate Reactive with Panache Repository: https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sandbox/blob/master/resteasy-reactive

Replace the `vertx-pg-client` with `vertx-oracle-client` and update SQL to Oracle compatible(for pgClient example) in your case.